# correct path uploads folder

Tags: wordpress

How am i getting the upload folder right in wordpress?

the path to achieve is : http://www.mydomain.com/uploads/year/month
the current path showing is http://www.mydomain.com/blog/../uploads/year/month

in the media settings i have ../uploads

the files are actually uploaded in the http://www.mydomain.com/uploads/year/month

the weird thing is that when you view source, it says the href="http://www.mydomain.com/blog/../uploads/year/month/theimagefile.jpg"

if i add in the media settings the full path http://www.mydomain.com/uploads, its just not recognized.

anyone have experience to deal with this?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried these settings

Store uploads in this folder: uploads

Full URL path to files:(Leave empty)

thanks

Comment: Thanks for the advice! 
added the full URL path http://www.mydomain.com/uploads and all works!!!! Mercy!